# Difference between $TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE != 'pull_request' and $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_SLUG != $TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG

Tags: travis-ci, chromatic

I am trying to set up Chromatic in Travis.

I saw [Chromatic document](https://docs.chromaticqa.com/setup_ci#travis) recommends using this script in Travis

```
if [[ $TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE != 'pull_request' || $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_SLUG != $TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG ]];
then
  npm run chromatic
fi
```

with explanation

> Travis offers two type of builds for commits on pull requests: so
>   called pr and push builds. It only makes sense to run Chromatic once
>   per PR, so we suggest disabling Chromatic on pr builds for internal
>   PRs (i.e. PRs that aren’t from forks). You should make sure that you
>   have push builds turned on, and add the following code: [[THE CODE ABOVE]]
>
> For external PRs (PRs from forks of your repo), the above code will
>   ensure Chromatic does run on the pr build, because Travis does not
>   trigger push builds in such cases.
>
> Note: We recommend running Chromatic on push builds as pr builds can't
>   always run and fall out of the normal git ancestry. For instance, if
>   you change the base branch of a PR, you may find that you need to
>   re-approve changes as some history may be lost.
>
> Chromatic does work with Travis pr builds however!

Then I read the [Travis document](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/) about `TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_SLUG` and `TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG`.

> TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_SLUG:
>
> - if the current job is a pull request, the slug (in the form
>     owner_name/repo_name) of the repository from which the PR originated.
> - if the current job is a push build, this variable is empty ("").
>
> TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG:
>
> - The slug (in form: owner_name/repo_name) of the repository currently being built.

So my understanding is when `$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_SLUG != $TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG`, it is a **push** build, then why it still needs `$TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE != 'pull_request'`?

Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gert from Chroma here.

We recommend to run chromatic only when a build does not originate from a pull request (i.e. a push build), OR when it is a pull request build originating from a fork, in which case the PR slug differs from the repo slug.

Based on the quoted Travis docs, in case of a push build, TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_SLUG is empty, in case of a PR build from a fork, it will reference the fork's repo owner. In either case it will be different from TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG. So you're correct that the left-hand side of this condition is superfluous. Feel free to omit it.